# short_id in sql with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple table Team: `id`, `short_id`, `name`, `championship_id`

What I need is that for each team `short_id` increments but only for one championship. When `championship_id` changes, `short_id` reset to 0.

I could do it manually, before creating I get `max(short_id)`, and insert the corresponding value, but I wonder if there is any better solution.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What does `short_id` mean in your system?

Comment: You could probably do it via [an Eloquent Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events), particularly the `saving` one.

Comment: @Mateusz I need to use an Id for each team, but it cannot be something like 983873. it should be an id between 1 and number of Teams